# MYSQL IN statement where values are case-insensitive

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to whitelist/blacklist based on user input with the following SQL statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City IN ('Paris','London');
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City NOT IN ('Paris','London');
```

What syntax is needed such that Paris and London are case insensitive and match paris and london?

Thanks.

Comment: Check collations for case insensitive http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the proper collation on your db fields and index will work fine too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

As you can see with `latin1_bin` `'MySQL' <> 'mysql'`

```
mysql> SET @s1 = 'MySQL' COLLATE latin1_bin,
    ->     @s2 = 'mysql' COLLATE latin1_bin;
mysql> SELECT @s1 = @s2;
+-----------+
| @s1 = @s2 |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

But with `latin1_swedish_ci` are equal

```
mysql> SELECT @s1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = @s2;
+-------------------------------------+
| @s1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = @s2 |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but if you've indexed `City` hoping to optimize the query, adding the `LOWER` function will kill the optimization:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE LOWER(City) IN ('paris', 'london');
```

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunate. Thanks a lot for the response!